# How i add price of product user role wise in wordpress woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, content-management-system

I want to make product price rate different different for different different user type
(eg: i have 5 types of users category 1, 2, 3....);
so i want to display product price different for each user type

Answer (score 0):

You can try achieving this using plugin 
->https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-role-based-price/
->https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-different-price-user/

Comment: Are you interested in code or you just want the solution from plugin? Please try to add more descriptive question.